# update data using loop in sql syntax

Tags: postgresql

I work with postgreSQL

I want  to update email of all my users  using sql

I have a table named `user` that contains 500 users,
so I think that  I should use a loop in my sql syntax

For example when the table contains 4 users, I want the email for these users to become :

```
user1@hotmail.fr
user2@hotmail.fr
user3@hotmail.fr
user4@hotmail.fr
```

in java it should be like this

```
 String newValue=null;
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
    {
    newValue="user"+i+"@hotmail.fr";
    // make update
    }
```

I think that I should use **plsql syntax**

**updated** :

I try without success with this code :

```
BEGIN

FOR r IN SELECT * from user_
    LOOP
    NEXT r;
    UPDATE user_ SET emailaddress = CONCAT('user',r,'@hotmail.fr')
    END LOOP;

END
```

Comment: We don't use loops in SQL to do this, as a single UPDATE statement can address all the rows of a table.

Comment: Use while loop in postgre SQL...

Comment: I have updated my question,I try without success with plsql code

Comment: What is `r` ? a record type? As @DanielVérité already said: you don't need a loop (and SQL per se does not *have* loops) Also : please add your table definition. ( `select *` is not very helpful)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using this query :

```
UPDATE user_ SET emailaddress='user' || col_serial || '@hotmail.fr' FROM 
(SELECT emailaddress, row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY createdate) AS col_serial FROM user_ ORDER BY createdate) AS t1 
WHERE user_.emailaddress=t1.emailaddress
```